# Why isn't IIS 7.5 picking up netsh iplisten list?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, netsh

When I execute the command

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

It returns a list of IP addresses I added manually:

```
IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------

a
b
c
```

However, when I run

```
netstat -an
```

None of the IPs above are listed. What is even weirder is when I try to add an http binding on a website through the IIS Management Console, the available IPs to choose from is d, e, f, g - even though I've specifically removed d. Of course, a, b, and c are not available.

I have already reinstalled IIS on the server. What else can I try beside reinstalling the server now?

Comment: How were the IPs added to the listen list - the `netsh` commands?  Is it still listening on 0.0.0.0, or was that removed?

Comment: Yes, they were added using `netsh` commands. No programs are listening to port 80 at 0.0.0.0. I didn't explicitly remove the binding.

Comment: Are there any bindings at all on port 80?  (IIS is running, right?)

Comment: Yes, it is, WWW Publishing service is running and the Management Console claims the server is running. Nothing is bound to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the web host assigned the wrong IPs. Even after adding the IP addresses to the network adapter and IP listen list, IIS somehow figured the IPs were not going to work and simply not list them.

I couldn't find anything in the event viewer to suggest IIS' failure to bind. Anyway, we now know how IIS deals with shady IP addresses and I wasn't crazy.